# Aligning table header column widths with table body when they're in different tables

Tags: html, css

I have a table header that needs (I believe) to stay in a separate table due to positioning reasons. What is the best way to tell the table header to determine its column spacing based on the tbody contents below that rest inside a different `<table>`? Due to some constraints in the structure of what I am working on it would be difficult to move these into the same table, so that probably isn't an option, unfortunately.

For example, I have something like this:

```
<table> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
            <th>Five</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<div>
    <p>Some keys here about what highlighted text below means</p>
</div>

<table> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The top table header is in a fixed position so the table and key will just scroll behind it as a user scrolls the table. I cannot figure out a way to get the `TH` to match the `TD`s below like they normally do when combined in the same table. Is there a trick I am unaware of to make them part of the same data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to ensure that both the tables has the same parent element. Then set the width of the `th` and first rows `td` tags to relative percentage, 
so that since both the elements have the same parent, their widths will match also. Like shown below.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

table {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="fix">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:20%">One</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Two</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Three</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Four</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Five</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<div>
  <p>Some keys here about what highlighted text below means</p>
</div>

<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20%">One</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Two</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Three</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Four</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Five</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This was for the table `td` issue. Now the position fixed for the header can be implemented like so.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.fix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

.offset {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="fix">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:20%">One</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Two</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Three</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Four</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Five</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<div class="offset">
  <p>Some keys here about what highlighted text below means</p>
</div>

<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20%">One</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Two</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Three</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Four</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Five</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```